# How can I use the RxJava2 library for the Apollo Client in Java properly for synchronous calls?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, rx-java2, apollo-client

[RxJava2](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/advanced/rxjava2/) is available for the  [Apollo GraphQL JVM](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started/). But I can figure out how to use it properly. I try to use it synchronously:

```
/**
 * This method is supposed to send an Apollo Call, map the data of the Responses into Optionals and 
 * give back the Optional<Data> object.
 * @param <T>: the build query
 * @param <V>: the expected data structure
 *
*/
    public static <T extends com.apollographql.apollo.api.Query> Optional<Data> execute(
            T operation) {
        ApolloClient client = new CommonClient().getClient();
        ApolloCall<Data> apolloCall = client.query(operation);
        return Rx2Apollo.from(apolloCall)
                .map(value -> Optional.of(value.data()))
                .onErrorReturn(o ->  {
                  logger.error(o.getMessage());
                  return Optional.empty();
                })
                .blockingFirst();
    }
```

But the problem is that I get an error on the .map(value -> Optional.of(value.data())) line. The error is:

> java.util.Optional cannot be cast to
> com.example.graphql.client.KundeQuery$Data

So, what am I doing wrong? Or is there at least an easier way to handle data in the Apollo GraphQL JVM Client synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got it. The incoming data structure is Response> and not >. So it wasnt able to read it. Solution might be this:

```
public static <T extends com.apollographql.apollo.api.Query> Optional<Data> execute(T operation) {

    ApolloClient client = new CommonClient().getClient();
    ApolloCall<Optional<Data>> apolloCall = client.query(operation);

    return Rx2Apollo.from(apolloCall)
            .map(IncomingResponse::extracted)
            .onErrorReturn(o -> {
                logger.error(o.getMessage());
                return Optional.empty();
                })
            .blockingFirst();
}

private static Optional<Data> extracted(Response<Optional<Data>> value) {
    Optional<Data> result = value.data();
    return result; //Optional.of(localData);
}
```